# Move to another View on PickerView Selecting Row

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipickerview

I have a picker view that has values already inside, for example one of the things inside is weather, I have a button that works with the picker view so when u pick weather and push the button an alert pops up and says Welcome to X. You selected Weather than u push OK to remove the alert, I was wondering if it was possible to after you push OK it takes you to the view controller that has the weather. I have never seen this done and this is an all in one app, also there are about 6 or 7 other items on the picker so if someone could help that would be great: here is my code. By the way I am new to the site sorry if I didn't do Code Blocks.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSArray *data = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Weather", @"Calendar", @"Facebook", @"Twitter", @"Instagram",@"Tasks" ,nil];
    self.array = data;


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}


#pragma marks Picker Data Source Methods

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    return [_array count];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {

    return 1;
}

#pragma mark Picker Delegate Methods

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    return [_array objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (IBAction)ButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    NSString *select = [_array objectAtIndex:[_picker selectedRowInComponent:0]];

    NSString *title = [ [NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"You selected %@!" , select];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:@"Welcome To One" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [alert show];


}
```

Comment: Guys the picker view works fine!!!!  its the question that i am asking! i want to use the picker view to go to another tableviewcontroller if that is possible! read the question!

Comment: Mention this in your question please

Comment: You wants to go to another tableviewcontroller when any row in pickerview is selected. am i right??

Comment: correct! exactly what i want to do.

Comment: after u select any row an alert appears and i want after you push ok to remove the alert it takes you to a tableviewcontroller

Comment: Use pickerview delegate method

Comment: does this work with the alert as well?

Comment: yes it will work `- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component;`

Comment: After clicking ok in alert, then only you need to push to another view controller ?

Comment: will try that thanks! new to coding just starting out so will take me some time to figure out where to put that,

Comment: I guess you given push in storyboard ? Give push to view controller by coding in alert view delegate method .

Comment: how would i do that? again new to coding...

Comment: @LUKA I GIVEN THE CODE ALREADY IN ANSWER ., CHECK MOHIT ANSWER ALSO .

Answer (score 2):

You have to do like bellow need to give tag to UIAlertView otherwise it will push view on each UIAlertView click

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:  (NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *select    = [_array objectAtIndex:component];
    NSString *title     = [ [NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"You selected %@!" , select];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:@"Welcome To One" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    alert.tag = 1001;
    alert.delegate = self;
    [alert show];
}
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag == 1001)
    {
        [self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Identifier" sender:nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
// Show alert here

    [[[UIAlertView alloc]
              initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Alert Message"
              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]

             show];

}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if (buttonIndex == 0)
{
    UIStoryboard * storyboard = self.storyboard;

        ViewController * detail = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"YourViewControlller"];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController: detail animated: YES];

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:  (NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *select = [_array objectAtIndex:component];
    NSString *title = [ [NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"You selected %@!" , select];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:@"Welcome To One" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    alert.delegate = self;
    [alert show];
}
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
    [self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Identifier" sender:nil];
    }
}
```